# Create Doughnut Chart Similar to Google Fit

Tags: android, user-interface, google-fit

Does anyone know how to create a doughnut chart similar to the one in Google Fit.

[image: Google Fit Chart]

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/txusballesteros/fit-chart I hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: If someone stills need a library that does that, here are some: For Java: - https://github.com/txusballesteros/fit-chart - https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart For Kotlin: - https://github.com/futuredapp/donut

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also wanted this, but the best answer i could find was "make your own".
So I did.

This is pretty basic (I'm new to android) and unfinished, but it should give you the idea.

Basically, you just set  up your paint objects

```
    paintPrimary = new Paint();
    paintPrimary.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintPrimary.setColor(colorPrimary);
    paintPrimary.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintPrimary.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```

and call canvas.drawArc

```
class FitDoughnutView extends View {

    private RectF _oval;

    public FitDoughnutView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawArc(_oval, 0, 360, false, paintSecondary);

        canvas.drawArc(_oval, 270, percentDeg, false, paintPrimary);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        _oval = new RectF(width, width, w - width, h - width);
    }
}
```

Full source here:
[github.com/tehmantra/fitdoughnut](https://github.com/tehmantra/fitdoughnut)

Someone's tutorial: [hmkcode.com/android-canvas-how-to-draw-2d-donut-chart/](http://hmkcode.com/android-canvas-how-to-draw-2d-donut-chart/)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [this library](https://github.com/futuredapp/donut) because it's actively maintained and has a lot of options.

It has a guide of [how to use it in Kotlin](https://github.com/futuredapp/donut), but you also can use it in Java like this:

In your layout file:

```
<app.futured.donut.DonutProgressView
        android:id="@+id/dpvChart"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:donut_bgLineColor="@color/grey"
        app:donut_gapAngle="270"
        app:donut_gapWidth="20"
        app:donut_strokeWidth="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Then in your Java Activity:

```
private DonutProgressView dpvChart;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    dpvChart = findViewById(R.id.dpvChart);

    DonutSection section = new DonutSection("Section 1 Name", Color.parseColor("#f44336"), 80.0f);
    dpvChart.setCap(100f);
    dpvChart.submitData(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(section)));
}
```

Comment: How does one implement clicking a slice? I wold want the slice to visually indicate that it's selected.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere where you can do that with this library. Maybe try with this one: https://github.com/furkanaskin/ClickablePieChart

Answer (score 0):

```
        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
          app:indicatorSize="60dp"
          android:progress="60"
          app:trackCornerRadius="10dp"
          app:trackThickness="10dp"
          app:trackColor="@color/white"
          app:indicatorColor="@color/teal_200"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```