# Android donut chart fill with multiple colors based on timestamp

Tags: java, android, google-fit, donut-chart

I am looking for a chart which will show one circle around that time like **12:00, 01:00** like. Which fills with some colors based on time of activity. 
I found this link [Create Doughnut Chart Similar to Google Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281238/create-doughnut-chart-similar-to-google-fit) but it isn't fit for my requirements.

Please find image below. This is how I am expecting the chart.

[image]

Here these colors represent some activity based on **timings**. I have a set of data with a timestamp and it's activity type.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can draw this chart? Is there any example for this?

### Edit

I found this link http://www.androidtrainee.com/draw-android-clock-pie-chart-with-animation/ to draw clock pie view. But stuck at point to set width and fill color like in above image. Right now it's fill different color based on time in full circle.  But how do I set width to this clock to fill color and center part blank to show **08:40**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since these are very specific requirements, it is likely that you will have to create your own **custom view** on Android. The SO you linked has a few promising libraries linked including [fit-chart](https://github.com/txusballesteros/fit-chart). The documentation isn't great, but it seems to support adding chart parts with values in 1% steps.

So you would only need to convert your duration data into percent of the circle by using 60 minutes or 12 hours as 100%.

Here is the relevant usage part of fit-chart:

```
Collection<FitChartValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(new FitChartValue(30f, 0x2d4302)); // 30f seems to represent 30%
final FitChart fitChart = (FitChart)findViewById(R.id.fitChart);
fitChart.setValues(values);
```

Another library that looks promising is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) that supports a detailed *Pie Chart*.

Regarding taking time into account: There are plenty of tutorials on how to draw an analogue clock that should include calculation on how to position the texts around the circle. Here is one [SO creating a `CustomClock` View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016368/android-programming-drawing-analog-clock)  with multiple tutorials linked.

Regarding setting up your custom view, [this 2d-donut-chart tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-canvas-how-to-draw-2d-donut-chart/) drawing a chart based on [`Path.arcTo`](http://hmkcode.com/android-canvas-how-to-draw-2d-donut-chart/) covers all the needed steps.

If you need further help it would be helpful if you add your data structure and what you already tried. But I hope with these libraries and tutorials you can create your desired view.

*Regarding updated question:* I would suggest that you create your own custom view. My best suggestion is to continue by comparing the `ClockPieView.onDraw` with the draw methods of the other libraries I mentioned that do draw a doughnut graph with a hole. Research how text can be rendered as part of the onDraw with your specific positioning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will go through your answer and get back to you.

Comment: is it possible to draw or show clock time around chart? like shown in image.

Comment: Please check my edit. I found one useful link. but stuck at one point.

Comment: @AjayPunekar I'm glad to hear you found a useful lib. I updated my answer with how I would continue. If you get stuck after investing more research and coding, I'd suggest including your code e.g. the relevant parts of your customView in a concrete new question about a specific issue. Keep in mind that SO is better working for concrete issues, not to get someone code your app ;-) See these tips on good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Heres a list of jQuery extensions to do this:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/02/jquery-html5-library-circular-piechart-graph.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already gone through this but didn't work. The challenge is to show color based on time.

Comment: How does jQuery help with Android? Isn't that a Javascript library?

Comment: @leoderprofi Sorry for confusion. Actually I modified this question to android. I am looking same for android as well as web.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the Pie chart of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to create this. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lynxu.png) is a similar one created using it.
Here you will find the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started) of the library and [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) demo application is also helpful.

Here is a sample code you can try out after adding MPAndroid chart library to your project.

```
List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
//add data entries, 100 will be considered as a full circle
entries.add(new PieEntry(50, ""));
entries.add(new PieEntry(25, ""));
entries.add(new PieEntry(25, ""));
PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "");
PieChart pieChart1 = (PieChart)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pie_chart1); 
pieChart.setMaxAngle(360); 
//You can customize the pie chart in many ways to suit your need
pieChart.setCenterTextRadiusPercent(84);
pieChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
pieChart.setRotationAngle(180);
pieChart.setHoleRadius(60f);
pieChart.setDescription(null);
pieChart.setHoleColor(ContextCompat
    .getColor(context,R.color.colorTransparent));
pieChart.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, 
    R.color.colorTransparent));
pieChart.setTouchEnabled(false)           
pieChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
pieChart.setCenterTextColor(Color.BLACK);
pieChart.setCenterTextSize(16f);
pieChart.setCenterText(status);  
//Add animation (optional)
pieChart.animateY(1500);
pieChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: The question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.